# why it throw the runtimeexception when running the application

Tags: scala

when i run the command:

> D:\scalaTest>fsc Summer.scala ChecksumAccumulator.scala
>
> D:\scalaTest>scala Summer hello world

the exception is :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot figure out how to run target: Summer
        at scala.sys.package$.error(package.scala:27)
        at scala.tools.nsc.GenericRunnerCommand.scala$tools$nsc$GenericRunnerCommand$$guessHowToRun(GenericRunnerCommand.scala:38)
        at scala.tools.nsc.GenericRunnerCommand$$anonfun$2.apply(GenericRunnerCommand.scala:48)
        at scala.tools.nsc.GenericRunnerCommand$$anonfun$2.apply(GenericRunnerCommand.scala:48)
        at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:108)
        at scala.tools.nsc.GenericRunnerCommand.<init>(GenericRunnerCommand.scala:48)
        at scala.tools.nsc.GenericRunnerCommand.<init>(GenericRunnerCommand.scala:17)
        at scala.tools.nsc.MainGenericRunner.process(MainGenericRunner.scala:33)
        at scala.tools.nsc.MainGenericRunner$.main(MainGenericRunner.scala:89)
        at scala.tools.nsc.MainGenericRunner.main(MainGenericRunner.scala)
```

this is the source codes includeing two scala files:

the one is Summer.scala:

```
import ChecksumAccumulator.calculate

object Summer {
  def main(args:Array[String]) {
    for(arg <- args)
      println(arg + ":" + calculate(arg))
  }
}
```

the another is ChecksumAccumulator.scala:

```
import scala.collection.mutable.Map

class ChecksumAccumulator {

  private var sum=0

  def add(b:Byte) { sum += b }

  def checksum():Int = ~(sum & 0xFF) + 1
}

object ChecksumAccumulator {

  private val cache = Map[String,Int]()

  def calculate(s:String):Int =
    if(cache.contains(s))
      cache(s)
    else {
      val acc = new ChecksumAccumulator
      for(c<-s)
        acc.add(c.toByte)
      val cs = acc.checksum()
      cache += (s->cs)
      cs
    }
}
```

**very thanks**

by the way: this is the example in the book "programming in scala 2nd.Edition" by Martin Odersky

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I had to guess, it's because your `CLASSPATH` environment variable doesn't include `.`.

So long as your `Summer.class` file is being generated correctly, you should be able to get it to run with

```
scala -cp . Summer hello world
```

Comment: good work!!!

the fact is that i just set the path and dont set the classpath with scala